# How can I compile and install that patched libata-eh.c file?

Tags: patch

I received a patched file. ( /drivers/ata/libata-eh.c ) from kernel mailing lists. and I have to compile and install it. But I'm not an  expert user really. Can anybody explain it simply ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I found the answer. But I'm not quite sure. Because developers have not sent a mail about it yet.

```
cd Downloads/linux-3.3.5/drivers/ata/

make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=$PWD

sudo make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=$PWD modules_install

sudo depmod -a

sudo update-initramfs -u
```